# How to send an push notification with image & badge using firebase in php?

Tags: php, mysql, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am really confusing how to send Firebase push notification with image & badge (real time counting of the notification) using PHP CURL?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer to this question would be yet another tutorial on this topic. However, if you are confused by the current tutorials, a new one may not help you either. So, rather than asking a very broad question, I would rewrite it to focus on the thing that confuses you.

Comment: okay, thanks. But i need real time badge counting of the push notification rather than send an notification. Thanks.

Comment: Well, then show your code and describe where you got stuck and I'm pretty sure you will get help. Your question in its current format unlikely to attract too many answers!

Comment: I'm working with the database and i need to use rest api for the badge counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the complete example of the real-time badge counting for the push notification.

```
function sendFCM($message ,$tokens ,$title)
{
    // For Badge Count
    global $conn;
    $badge = 1;
    foreach ($tokens as $key => $valueTokens) 
    {
        $getBadgeQ = "SELECT badge FROM tablename WHERE token = '".$valueTokens."' ";
        $getBadgeE = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, $getBadgeQ));
        $badge = $badge + $getBadgeE['badge'];
        $updateQ = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE tablename SET badge = '".$badge."' WHERE token = '".$valueTokens."' ");
    }
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $key = '<your api server key>';
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $tokens,
        'notification' =>array('title' => $title, 'body' =>  $message , 'badge'=>$badge, 'sound'=>'Default','image'=>'<full path of the image>' ),
    );   
    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $key,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);// skip ssl certificate verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $err = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($err) {
        return $err;
    } else {
        return (json_decode($response));
    }
}

$message = "This is test message..!!";
$title = "Testing Push";
$tokens[] = "<your device token>";

$response = sendFCM($message ,$tokens ,$title);
```